# What is happening in this review process?

Tags: peer-review, journals, paper-submission

This is in reference to my recent submission I made on Theoretical and Mathematical Physics journal published by the Russian Academy of Sciences. A screenshot of the status terminal is as follows. If anyone has some experience publishing with this journal can you please let me know what is happening? What is this 'Letter'? And how much time it usually takes to review the revision in this journal?[image]

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a Does this answer your question?

Comment: Also whenever you have a question about a particular publisher/product is much better to directly ask*them* about it!

Comment: We don't really want to host these questions for every possible iteration of journal statuses for every possible publisher and submission. They're unlikely to have long term meaning as the software changes all the time, and there's simply very little an author can glean from them. Editors communicate with authors when their input is needed.